# Casperjs does not redirect if there is a 'let' in javascript

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

For example this is the source of an html page: `example.html`

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {

    }
    window.location = 'http://example.com';
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Execute the command to open the `example.html` page with `casperjs`

`casper.start('example.html')`

The result I had not expected. `casperjs` cannot be redirected to `http://example.com`

But if I edited the `example.html` page above by replacing in `for`

`let i = 0` ~~> `var i = 0`

everything worked out for me. `casperjs` will be redirected to `http://example.com`

How can I fix this situation with every website?

Answer (score 0):

CasperJS is based on PhantomJS which is very outdated in terms of Javascript capabilities and does not support ES6 at all (and `let` is a feature of ES6) and it is absolutely not possible to polyfill a keyword.

Since the PhantomJS [is suspended](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344) it is strongly advised to move to another tool. I'd suggest [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) which is being actively developed by Google and has great [community support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/puppeteer).